# Unable to split cell content by line breaks

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA script is supposed to split content in one cell by line breaks into several rows, it works for some cells, date in one cell look like this:

```
a01gestmstrs2a 10.67.15.17 
a01gestmdb2a   10.67.15.19
a01gstdbldnim1a
a01rstdbldnim1a
a01gestmstrs2b (10.67.15.46)
a01restmdb2a (10.67.15.48)
a01gestmstrs2z 10.67.15.20 
a01gestmdb2b (10.67.15.47)
a01restmstrs2a (10.67.15.49)
```

However, it fails to split for some such as the sample provided above, I can't figure out why.
My code:

```
Sub SplitMultipleHostnames()
Dim tmpArr As Variant
Dim s As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each cell In Range("D2", Range("D3").End(xlDown))
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    s = c.Value
    If Trim(Application.Clean(s)) <> s Then
        s = Trim(Application.Clean(s))
        c.Value = s
    End If


If cell.Value <> "" Then
    If InStr(1, cell, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then
        tmpArr = Split(cell, Chr(10))

        cell.EntireRow.Copy

        cell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(tmpArr), 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown



        cell.Resize(UBound(tmpArr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(tmpArr)

    End If


Else
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
    cell.Row = cell.Row - 1

End If
Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not actually Char(10) they are spaces. I changed the code to " " and it worked fine

```
  If cell.Value <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, cell, " ") <> 0 Then
                    tmpArr = Split(cell, " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

The loop that uses **Trim()** and **Clean()** will remove all ASCII 10's and 13's from the worksheet.

There will be nothing to **Split()**.